# visual studio 2015 doesn't see the header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, include, wdk

I'm trying to compile project connected with drivers, but VS doesn't see the header files *ntddk.h* and *vadefs.h*. I've found both of them located in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\km
```

[image: proof for ntddk.h]

added them in projects properties:

[image: added adress]

but it stil doesn't work..

Comment: How are you including the files? With `#include <file>` or `#include "file"`?

Comment: #include <file>

Comment: this makes the compiler search for the file in _system_ directories, which you probably don't want.

Comment: replaced with 
 `#include "ntddk.h"` and `#include "vadefs.h"`
but the problem's still there.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a `$` before the path, so it's getting confused and treating it as if you want a macro called `$C:\Program` which you don't have. Just use this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\km\;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```